# Microsoft Custom Vision only work for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, azure-cognitive-services

**The Problem:**
When I try to install the packages for Microsoft Custom Vision in VS 2013, it fails. Does Custom Visions just not compatible with VS 2013, or is there another problem here?

When I try to install the Custom Vision package **after the first failed attempt** (without uninstalling Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime 2.3.2), I get a different response, as seen below:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime (≥ 2.3.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 6.0.8)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.IO.FileSystem (≥ 4.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Net.Http (≥ 4.3.1)'.
Installing 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0'.
Successfully installed 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0'.
Installing 'System.Net.Http 4.3.1'.
Successfully installed 'System.Net.Http 4.3.1'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Training 1.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Training 1.0.0'.
Adding 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0' to WpfApplication2.
Uninstalling 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For 
more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Training
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Can anyone tell me what this means, or offer a potential fix?

**Qualifier:**
My development team all use Visual Studio 2013, so I'd rather not change to 2015 or 2017.

***UPDATE:*** I have succumb to stress and installed VS 2017- still getting the same error:

```
Could not install package 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 can be installed into a project that targets .NET Framework 4.6.

So I would just change the target framework of your project to .NET 4.6.

Comment: Yes, the SDKs have a minimum target of .NET 4.6 and above.